# google classroom events don't show on google calendar api

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I am trying to write a program that gets the google calendar events for the following week and lists them
but when I run the code it only shows events I created manually and not events like holidays and Google Classroom assignments

this is the code

```
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, timeMax=in_a_week, singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    yield (start, event["summary"])
```

this is the output

```
No upcoming events found.
```

I checked the datetime object and they work ok with manually created events

what should I do?